# Backbone JS scroll event handling

Tags: jquery, underscore.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I am trying to implement scroll event in backbone JS using JQuery and underscore. in initialize function I add below lines :

```
 _.bindAll(this, 'filter_list');
 $(window).scroll(this.filter_list);
```

where filter_list is function from where I am trying to fetch data for next 50 entries in DB.

For the first time, the page display 100 records from DB. On the scroll hit bottom of page, the filter_list function gets called which has logic to fetch next 50 entries from DB.

The scroll event hits when scroll bar is at the bottom of page however instead of call filter_list once, the scroll event is called multiple times, which ends up fetching same data from DB multiple times. Add the same results get updated to the page, i.e. same 50 records displayed multiple time.

I tried registering event in different ways but of no use. Also if anyone can explain the scroll event and binding mechanism in backbone JS then it would be great, I didn't get any good stuff on internet.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable example](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/) of your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [scroll event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll) is fired every time the scroll bar moves, you need to do all the fetching logic yourself. Here is an idea:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'filter_list');
    // also good idea to debounce
    this.filter_list = _.debounce(this.filter_list, 300);
    // Keep internal fetching state
    this.isFetching = false;
    $(window).scroll(this.filter_list);  
  },

  filter_list: function() {
    if (this.scrollHitPageBottom() && !this.isFetching) {
      this.isFetching = true;
      this.fetchDBEntries()
          .finally(function() { this.isFetching = false });
    }
  },

  ... 
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am bale to get event using - if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() + 1 >= $(document).height()){}, However the problem is, I get bottom hit event multiple times. So because of that same request is sent to DB many time and all the results are appended to page. I tried using _.debounce but not of much you :(

Comment: After some more testing I came across that the render function is getting called multiple times on scroll hit bottom event handling. On scroll bottom hit event handling I am calling this.collection.fetch () function. Which changes the data. Since the render function is already bind to any reset, it re-renders.     However the problem is, when for the first time on page the render function get called once but after every data in data the render functions start getting called multiple times.